# infinite recursion when printing instance in python

Tags: python, recursion, instance

I get a Runtime error (maximum recursion) when I execute the following code.
I'm trying to generate a list of instances; then I would like to print each one. I'm not sure what's going on here. 
Anyway, what is the correct way to access each instance from the instance list?

I do realize I'm using a string of digits to name the instances and this is not cool. But say each number on the list is associated with a bunch of information. Then having attributes for each could make things accessible. I tried using a dict but I end up with nested dicts and I just didn't like it.

Thanks in advance.

```
class MyClass(object):
  def __str__(self):
    stuff= str(self)
    return stuff


mylist = ['1234567','8910111','1213144','7654321']

inslist = [MyClass() for i in mylist]

print inslist[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `__str__`. If you call `str(self)`, it will call itself. I think you meant was this:

```
class MyClass(object):
  def __init__(self, i):
     self.i = i
  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.i)


mylist = ['1234567','8910111','1213144','7654321']

inslist = [MyClass(i) for i in mylist]

print inslist[0]
```

Comment: Dang it! I almost came up with the solution. Thank you.